# Adding AjaxEventBehavior to form's button prevents form from submitting with Wicket 6.1 and 6.2

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I have a simple `FormPage` derived from `WebPage` defined like this:

```java
public FormPage() {

    final FeedbackPanel feedback = new FeedbackPanel("feedback");
    add(feedback);

    final TextField<String> entry = new TextField<String>("entry");

    final Button button = new Button("button");
    button.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick") {
        @Override
        protected void onEvent(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            System.out.println("Event");
        }
    });

    Form<DataModel> form = new Form<User>("userForm", new CompoundPropertyModel<DataModel>(dataModel)) { 

        @Override
        protected void onValidate() {
            System.out.println("Validate");
            String entryValue = entry.getValue();
            if (entryValue == null || entryValue.length() == 0) {
                error("entry value required");
            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit() {
            System.out.println("Submit");
            if (!hasErrors()) {
                String entryValue = entry.getValue();
                if (!entryValue.equals("value")) {
                    error("entry has wrong value");
                }
            }
        };
    };

    form.add(entry);
    form.add(button);
    add(form);
}
```

I'm trying to do something (in this example just printing to console) on form submission, so I've attached `AjaxEventBehavior` on button's `onclick` event. This works perfectly: action is performed on button click, but now the form is not being submitted.

I also was experimenting with

```java
form.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onsubmit")
```

and this event handler also prevents form submission.
For example,

```java
entry.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick")
```

allows form to be submitted, but the event is not related to submission.
Now I'm puzzled how can I have my form submitted and perform some action on this event.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default in Wicket 6, a behavior attached to a component prevents the default component action from happening.

If you want to trigger both the behavior and the component action you have to override the updateAjaxRequestAttributes method in your behavior:

```
@Override
protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
    super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
    attributes.setAllowDefault(true);
}
```